# Security and Privacy settings grayed out

Tags: macos

MacBook Pro 2020 core i5
MacOS 12.3.1
This is a work laptop.

Under my security and privacy settings, options for require password and allow apps downloaded from are disabled (grayed out). Even when I unlock these settings and the padlock logo shows open these items are still unavailable.

I am on an admin account with admin privileges. I have even tried creating a whole other admin account and try to change these settings from there but did not work.

My guess is that my work has disabled these items from the terminal commands. How can I enable these again? Thank you!

*Please note that unlocking with apple watch does not affect this setting because this situation existed before I had an Apple Watch too.

[image]

Comment: "This is a work laptop." is probably the key, you're locked down by the corporate MDM policy. You'll need to ask your IT department.

Comment: I don't have any profile or profile & device management under my preferences so I'm assuming my Mac does not have MDM profile. @Tetsujin